# Youtube video double click

Tags: asp.net, html, youtube

I have embedded you tube video into my project.The problem which i'm facing is that when i double click on that video it opens in new tab.What i want is that when i click that video it should open in full screen.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Open in full screen is the behavior of the player when used on YouTube. Open a new tab is the behavior when the player is embedded in anther webpage.

It seems that modify this behavior is a  violation of the YouTube Terms of Service 4(f) 4.

> General Use of the Service—Permissions
>   and Restrictions    F. If you use the
>   Embeddable Player on your website, you
>   may not modify, build upon, or
>   block any portion or   functionality
>   of the Embeddable Player, including
>   but not              limited to links
>   back to the YouTube website.
>   http://www.youtube.com/t/terms

Answer (score 2):

to goto full screen add following inside object tag:

```
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
```

to prevent opening new window of youtube, set following inside the object tag :

```
<param name="allownetworking" value="internal">
```

for example:

```
<object width="558" height="440" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
data="http://www.youtube.com/v/HyJBnmO8O8o?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" id="sb-player">
    <param name="allownetworking" value="internal">
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
</object>
```

and please make sure you abide by the `Terms & Conditions of Youtube - http://www.youtube.com/t/terms`

Comment: It has prevented double click.But the problem is when i double click on the video,it doesn't open in fullscreen

Comment: once the video is played, you can easily switch to full screen by double clicking the video.

Comment: you can set the `autoplay` to `1` so that user do not have to click first time to play the video.

Answer (score 1):

it is a default behavior of youtube player

Comment: Opening in new tab is default behaviour? How can i override taht

Comment: I have seen a link where it opens in fullscreen.This is the link

Comment: well m afraid that you cant do any thing to stop thsi as this is a default behaviour of YouTube player. if you wana do this then use another flash player rather then YouTube

Comment: @Hansmukh, you can surely override the default behaviour of youtube player, check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184423/youtube-video-double-click/4184947#4184947